# Can Selenium webdriver and splinter webdriver be used for the same browser

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I know splinter is built on top of selenium but I can't seem to figure out how to get splinter and selenium to use the same web browser.

I can initialize splinter browser

```
browser = splinter.Browser('chrome', options=chrome_options)
```

and I can initialize a selenium browser

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

but this will launch two different browsers.

Is it possible to get splinter and selenium to share the same browser?

Comment: I think it is impossible.

Comment: It's technically possible. Try to instantiate a `RemoteWebDriver` from Selenium with the underling command executor from Splinter.

Comment: @FlorentB. you mean something like? browser = splinter.Browser('chrome', options=chrome_options) driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=browser, desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME) I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute' when I try that

Answer (score 3):

You actually already have an instance of the selenium driver WITH whatever Chrome options you launched through splinter:

Splinter:

```
browser = splinter.Browser('chrome', options=chrome_options)
```

Selenium:

```
selenium_driver = browser.driver
```

Cheers :)